# Power series for a matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

Is there a power series expansion for a matrix inverse of the form
$$\left(\frac{1}{m}I+A\right)^{-1} \mbox{ where $m$ is a scalar?}$$

$A$ is not invertible but the expression above is defined. I don't want to embed $m$ into the $A$ matrix as I want the result to have $m$ in it explicitly.

Thanks!

Comment: Power series for small $m$, or for large $m$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have
$$
\left(\frac{1}{m}I+A\right)^{-1}=m(I+mA)^{-1}=m\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nm^nA^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nm^{n+1}A^n.
$$
The series above (known as *Neumann series*) converges whenever
$$
\lvert m\rvert\cdot\|A\| <1.
$$

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then the series converges for $m$ large.

Comment: Could you elaborate on convergence for $m$ large? In my case $m \approx 10$ and I would like to estimate the quality of approximation using Neumann series

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, these type of sums are called Neumann's series. $\frac{1}{I-M}=\sum_0^\infty M^k$ under the "right" assumption on $M$. Operator $M$ should be bounded, you have that for free since you deal with matrices, and series converges in norm.

Comment: Well, to get an equation of the form $\dfrac{1}{I-M}$, you have to embed $m$ into $A$, which is what the OP does *not* want.

Comment: Well $(\frac{1}{m}I-A)^{-1}=m(I-mA)^{-1}$