# Least additive modification to a matrix to make it invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, soft-question, inverse

Would it be well defined? Say I have a matrix $\bf A$ which I know is not invertible. Is there some way to define the "minimal added contribution" $\bf B$ that will make it invertible?

---

**Own work:** I've been thinking maybe something like this will make it well defined in some sense: $$\min_{\bf B,P}\{\epsilon_1\|(\bf A+ B)P-I\|+ \epsilon_2\|B\|\}$$ Where $\bf P$ is the candidate inverse. But I doubt it would be very well behaved since $\bf B$ and $\bf P$ are multiplied together.

Comment: Well no, because invertible matrices are dense in $GL_n(\Bbb K)$ for $\Bbb K = \Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any matrix $A$, $A + \epsilon I$ will be invertible for sufficiently small nonzero $|\epsilon|$.

Comment: Of course you are right, I will need to figure out what more requirements I would want which I forgot to formulate. But I will do that in another question.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @Vincent https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705758

Comment: @Vincent $A + \epsilon I$ fails to be invertible iff $-\epsilon$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to find is an addition that would make $\det (A+B)\ne 0$. Now since $\det A$ is a polynomial in the elements of $A$ you would have that there are arbitrarily small such additions.

Comment: Maybe i can find a "direction" where the determinant increases the fastest from the current $\bf A$? Would it be reasonable since polynomials are smooth differentiable functions?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, except of course the possibility that the least degree terms are quadratic or higher and there are a set of directions where the determinant increases/decreases equally fast. An example for this is $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Then maybe that is an approach I could go for. Trying to check the partial differentials to the determinant wrt individual matrix element and then go in the gradient direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the the least $k$ such that changing the values of $k$ elements of $A$ results in an invertible matrix, then $n-r$, where $A$ has order $n$ and rank $r$.

Comment: Thank you for identifying what I should have asked!